# Is it possible to show or hide columns in grid (similar to collapse and expand option in VISUAL STUDIO)

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a problem where columns must be hidden/show when + or - is clicked(+/- will be another column in the grid.)

```
==============================================================
 - | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 |
==============================================================
```

when the `-` is clicked is should be shown as

```
=======
 + 
=======
```

All the columns (Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4) would be hidden, on clicking `+` it would be expanded again.

Note
1. The columns will be known only in run time. There will be three types of similar columns like this. But the hide or show will work like the above one.

Please share if you have come across any controls (ready made/ tweaked ) asp.net/ jquery controls.

Thanks
Vino

Answer (score 0):

The `Infragistics` `igGrid` supports such functionality. You can see a sample here:

[igGrid Column Hiding](http://www.infragistics.com/products/jquery/sample/grid/column-hiding-basic)

Answer (score 0):

if you need to show/hide columns on the client side you can use jqgrid

[jqgrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

(in left menu:  New since beta 3.0/Hide/Show Columns)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this FREE jQuery grid plugin named DataTables.net - [www.datatables.net](http://www.datatables.net)

And [this](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html) example which shows how to show hide the columns using the fnSetColumnVis() function.

Comment: Is it possible to have this functionality as another column in the grid as (+ and -).

Comment: No link-only answers please. Can you quote the example here?